# UTF-8 difference between oracle and java

Tags: java, oracle, unicode, utf-8

I have the following unicode difference between an oracle database and Java.

If I run the following in oracle sql developer:

```
select unistr('\008C') from dual;
```

I get the following unicode character: 
http://www.utf8icons.com/character/140/control-character

However, if I try to perform the same type of unicode code to string conversion in java :

```
String s1 = new String("\u008C");
```

I get an empty char as a result.

I understand I could use the \u0152 character that displays the character I need in both java and oracle properly, but I would like to understand why I have this difference. I tried playing with my fonts but I did not get to any decent result. Thanks.

Comment: How are testing the output of your Java? Where are you printing it to?

Comment: My bad, I copied the wrong line of code(after performng many tests this arvo), I changed my question, this has effectively only to do with the \u008C character not displaying the same thing in Java and oracle

Comment: `String s1 = new String("\u008C", "UTF-8");` is also invalid. `"\u008C"` is a Unicode point, not UTF-8 encoded so you don't need to decode. You should simply do: `String s1 = "\u008C"`. Then it's important to tell us how you're seeing this output. Console, Web Page, text file?

Comment: I'm an idiot, I actually did not have the encoding either in my test... Anyway, I got the problem in the eclipse debug, system outprint and using a jaxrs cxf interface I got an odd <98> character when performing a curl request. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So it's resolved then?

Comment: no, I still don't understand why oracle properly displays the attached oe while I see an empty char in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes no sense:

```
String s1 = new String("\u008C".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

If you're lucky, your default encoding will be UTF-8 and you'll get:

```
s1.equals("\u008C") == true
```

this is because `.getBytes()` will default to your system encoding. You're effectively, encoding to an unknown (but discoverable) encoding and decoding from UTF-8.

If you're unlucky, your default encoding will be something else and you'll have emojibaked your string.

If what you meant to say was:

```
 System.out.println( "\u008C" );
```

produces nothing, it's because 'PARTIAL LINE BACKWARD' is a control character. i.e it's non-printing. It should never be printed. It would seem that some UI's render this character as 'LATIN CAPITAL LIGATURE OE' (U+0152) automatically and is dependent on implementation.

For example, if I copy create an HTML document with `&#x8c;` in it, it displays in Chrome as Œ. Copy this char into your clipboard and paste into into a document and save it as UTF-16 BE. Hex dump the file and you will see:

```
0000000 01 52
```

The Unicode code point / UTF-16 encoding of 'LATIN CAPITAL LIGATURE OE'. Therefore, the Oracle SQL Developer tool is just deceiving/helping you by displaying 'LATIN CAPITAL LIGATURE OE' instead.

Answer (score 1):

`String.getBytes()` converts a string into sequence of bytes using the platform default encoding. It is equivalent to :

```
String encoding = System.getProperty("file.encoding");
"\u008C".getBytes( encoding );
```

A result of this function is dependent on the encoding you have. 
For example on my PC there is cp1250 codepage, and I get this result:

```
    System.out.println( System.getProperty("file.encoding") );
    byte b[] = "\u008C".getBytes();
    for( byte bb: b)System.out.format("%x\n", bb);
    -------
    Cp1250
    3f
```

As you see, the Œ character was converted to one byte: 3f, which in cp1250 is ? character. I belive this is because there is no Œ character in cp1250, so CharsetEncoder (which is used by toBytes() method to convert from unicode strings to a specufic charset) converts Œ to ? in this case.
See here for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html

As you see, your java code is converting unicode string to your platform encoding, then the result (as byte array) is treated as unicode again - but in fact it is encoded using some other encoding.
This doesn't make sense.